# Layout encourages accidental clicks - interstitial ads - admob

Tags: admob

So basically I got an email this morning saying that Interstitial ads that load unexpectedly while a user is viewing the app’s content.

Basically The app loads ads on view-pager swipe(after the 4th swipe/click) and on selection of menu drawer(after the 3rd click) and on opening news content, what do I need to do to avoid this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very careful not to break Admob's rules, because once you are banned you are banned for a long time.

Admob have tons of info on this - see https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362

You haven't explained the issue well but -

- Make sure you cache ads before showing them. That is when you start your app immediately load an ad (so it is ready to display, don't display it yet). When you swipe or page or click menu then display the ad. There will be no delay in it displaying as it has already been loaded. Then load the next one straight away so you have it ready to display the next time.
- You must display ads BETWEEN different pages of info. You cannot be viewing some info and just have an interstitial pop up in the middle of your viewing. If you make an ad request and the ad takes two seconds or something to show, then it will appear to the user (and Google) that it has just popped up in the middle of what they are doing. CACHE the ads so they show straight away - see above.

Answer (score 0):

Stop showing your ads async. You should only ever call `ad#show()` at a natural breakpoint in your app. If you don't have a naturqal breakpoint, then your app is not a good fit for interstitial ads.